# Let's burninate [api]

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

(Slightly related to this question: [Questions of the form: Does {website X} have an API?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3933/354))

**Application Program Interfaces** are firmly in the domain of programming. Except, perhaps, for questions asking where to find a particular web app's API, questions about APIs are going to be off-topic here.

Given that, [api](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) looks like it fits the definition of a meta-tag. We don't allow general API questions, so it can't work as the only tag on a question. It will need to have the context of the web app being asked, and presumably a tag for that will be on the question.

So I think we should remove it from the <s>74</s> 33 questions where it currently exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burninated. Tag itself is deleted.