# Using LINE from Python, is it on-topic and how to find existing questions and answer?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, search

I'd like to see if there are existing questions and answers here about the LINE application and a possible Python API for it (e.g. [1](https://github.com/shlee322/python-line-api), [2](https://carpedm20.github.io/line/), [3](https://pypi.org/project/line_notify/))

However, searching the site for "LINE" is the same as searching for the generic word "line" and so returns 1,700+ results. There is no [line-app](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-app) tag. Even searching PyPI is a challenge!

**Questions:**

1. How can I search this site for questions and answers about LINE?
2. Might asking about a possible Python API for LINE possibly be on-topic (of course it depends on the specific question)?

---

> [image: searching for "LINE" returns 1,700+ results!]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I ask a question about developing web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4685/where-can-i-ask-a-question-about-developing-web-applications)

Comment: @serenesat [it has](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4726/224799)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use LINE we have to download/install something, it can't used by typing/clicking a link, so it's off-topic here.

Questions about API's usually are off-topic here.

Because LINE is off-topic here, it doesn't make sense to have a tag for it so, there isn't a easy way to find posts that are about LINE.

Related

- [Are API questions on topic or off topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/740/88163)
- [Questions of the form: Does {website X} have an API?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3933/88163)
- [Where can I ask a question about developing web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4685/88163)

Comment: It's pretty conclusive so I'll accept immediately. Thanks for your time and clear explanation, it really helps!